# Android studio 1.5+ error type 3 - Activity class does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 1.5 and now every project that I try to Run or debug shows, Activity class does not exist. Solutions that **I tried and failed** are listed below.

1. Clean build
2. Rename Activity class
3. Restart IDE
4. Upgrade to Android Studio 2.0 Preview
5. Install new build tools

Comment: Is this a Gradle error or something else? Does your Gradle build run at all?

Comment: Yes the gradle build is successful

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

I realized i've moved all dependencies to my library project. My project compiles with no warnings, but always gives me "segmentation fault" when try to run it.

I duplicated library dependencies to the apk project, and now it starts.

Don't mix dependencies 22.x and 23.x

I hope that this trick works for you too!

Try disable the ADB integration ( Tools- > Android- > Enable Integration) That worked for me. That's the key!

Comment: I'm not adding any dependencies to my project, it's a very basic android project with only the default Activity and the default layout file, and no other fancy stuff.

Comment: Try disable the ADB integration ( Tools- > Android- > Enable Integration)
That worked for me.

Comment: Tried that as well. I even installed a fresh copy of Android Studio and downloaded the SDK and build tools again. The problem remains unsolved

Answer (score 0):

Strange problem , stranger solution. I tried the app on lollipop and now it works fine. I had been installing on Marshmallow (Android 6.0) both on emulator and my device. Though this is not a solution, we can close the question for now.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue when using my own phone (API 18) instead of emulator. Then, after uninstall the previous version of my App, run and install it again, everything worked well... So, I suggest this approach, its worth trying.